# Is it a good idea to think of defining a DCAT vocabulary in other languages?

Tags: metadata

IMHO, [Project Open Data](http://project-open-data.github.io/schema/) does a great job defining a standard metadata vocabulary based on [DCAT](http://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-dcat/) for government datasets.

Would it be a good idea to start defining DCAT metadata terms in other languages, for example, "título" (Spanish) instead of "title" (English)?

Is that something [W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) should be looking at? Or something that should be patched through an [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)?

Comment: Much of the DCAT values look to be carried over from DCMI (Dublin Core) ... you might just be able to map the values to a schema that someone's already translated.

Comment: Sure, mapping to another schemas could be an option. But we decided to keep the english key terms for the sake of compliance.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend translating standard schema terms to other languages. This would make datasets not portable across toolsets that incorporate the schema. Instead, I would suggest mapping the terms to other languages in the visualization (e.g., viewer) of the data.

For example, an spreadsheet view in English might show "title" while in Spanish how "titulo". But the field naming in the raw data would not change.